Media Wiki Templates
I am very new to mediawiki and ddeveloping with it.
Goal: to create a leader board page that dynamically populates users and there stats.
Leaderboard
{{UserScore

| Username = Timmy

| Score = 100

| Badges = 5

}}

LeaderBoard is showing data like this: 

{{#vardefine: Username|Timmy}} {{#vardefine: Score|100}} {{#vardefine: Badges|5}}

Not sure why or how to display better.


Template:UserScore

<includeonly>{{ #vardefine: Username | {{{Username}}} }}</includeonly>
<includeonly>{{ #vardefine: Score | {{{Score}}} }}</includeonly>
<includeonly>{{ #vardefine: Badges | {{{Badges}}} }}</includeonly>




It looks like you haven't installed the extension Variables.
But you shouldn't have anyway. Variables were meant to reuse the same data within one page; and even that they can no longer do, due to changes in wiki parsing.
To display the data, define Template:UserScore like this:
{| class="infobox"
! Username || {{{Username|{{PAGENAME}}}}}
|-
! Score || {{{Score|0}}}
|-
! Badges || {{{ Badges|}}}
|}

To query that data from other pages, you might want to install Semantic MediaWiki or Cargo.
if you have installed Semantic MediaWiki, redefine Template:UserScore like this:
{| class="infobox"
! Username || {{{Username|{{PAGENAME}}}}} {{#set:Username={{{Username|{{PAGENAME}}}}}}}
|-
! Score || {{{Score|0}}} {{#set:Score={{{Score|0}}}}}
|-
! Badges || {{{ Badges|}}} {{#set:Has badge={{{Badges|}}}|+sep=,}}
|}

Create Property:Username as (some description) {{#set:Has type=Text}}, Property:Score as (some description) {{#set:Has type=Number}} and Property:Has badge as (some description) {{#set:Has type=Page}}.
Then you can query, e.g. on the page The Sublime Badge of Everlasting Honour:
The following people have the badge {{PAGENAME}}:
{{#ask: [[Has badge::{{FULLPAGENAME}}]]
| ?Username
}}

The examples I have given are too primitive for production use, but you can make them more complex afterwards.

Thank you for your answer. I am tracking and so far I manage to see a leaderboard data as expected. Could you elaborate more on the text you wrote about Create Property:Username as (some description) {{#set:Has type=Text}}, Property:Score as (some description) {{#set:Has type=Number}} and Property:Has badge as (some description) {{#set:Has type=Page}}. I am not sure I fully understand this.

@Timmy Create a page named Property:Username (the same way you would create, say, Template:UserScore) with at least the content {{#set:Has type=Text}}, and if you want, you can add some plain text description. Do the same for the other examples.
